# Family table query mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to learn simple SQL with below family table structure, where `parent_id` is a relation of `family.id` (same table)

| id | name | gender | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Adam | male | NULL |
| 2 | Alvin | male | 1 |
| 3 | Chris | male | 1 |
| 4 | Michael | male | 1 |
| 5 | Lala | female | 1 |
| 6 | Matt | male | 2 |
| 7 | Fay | female | 2 |
| 8 | Percy | male | 3 |
| 9 | Jackson | male | 3 |
| 10 | Hana | female | 4 |
| 11 | Hani | female | 4 |

I have the following questions that I have not finished and the sql progress that I made

1.Create a query to get the aunt of Fay

```
SELECT aunt.*
FROM family AS aunt
JOIN family AS parent ON aunt.parent_id = parent.id
JOIN family AS cousin ON parent.id = cousin.parent_id
WHERE cousin.id = 7 AND aunt.gender = 'female';
```

2.Create a query to get the male cousin of Hana

```
SELECT male_cousin.*
FROM family AS cousin
JOIN family AS parent ON cousin.parent_id = parent.id
JOIN family AS grandparent ON parent.parent_id = grandparent.id
JOIN family AS male_cousin ON grandparent.id = male_cousin.parent_id
WHERE cousin.id = 10 AND male_cousin.gender = 'male';
```

I know my query is wrong but that's the extent of my ability at the moment.

Comment: are you getting errors / wrong results?

Comment: for question number 1 is wrong result (result is "farah", it should be "lala") | 
for question number 2 worng too (result is alvin chris michael, it should be matt percy jackson)

Comment: I am thinking through Q1 (by the way, it's better to have one question at a time) - what is "farah" - I don't see it in the list

Answer (score 1):

Should be

```
SELECT aunt.*
FROM family AS aunt
JOIN family AS parent ON aunt.id = parent.parent_id
JOIN family AS fay ON fay.parent_id = parent.id
WHERE fay.name = 'Fay' AND aunt.gender = 'female';
```

and

```
SELECT male_cousin.*
FROM family AS cousin
JOIN family AS parent ON cousin.parent_id = parent.id
JOIN family AS hana ON hana.parent_id = parent.id
JOIN family AS male_cousin ON male_cousin.parent_id = parent.id
WHERE hana.name = 'Hana' AND male_cousin.gender = 'male';
```

Comment: pardon, but your answer is wrong too, it's showing empty result

Comment: ahah yeah it could be sorry i cant test the code rn

Comment: try ```SELECT aunt.*
FROM family AS fay
JOIN family AS parent ON fay.parent_id = parent.id
JOIN family AS aunt ON parent.parent_id = aunt.parent_id
WHERE fay.name = 'Fay' AND aunt.gender = 'female';```

Comment: and `SELECT cousin.*
FROM family AS hana
JOIN family AS parent ON hana.parent_id = parent.id
JOIN family AS cousin ON parent.id = cousin.parent_id
WHERE hana.name = 'Hana' AND cousin.gender = 'male';`